# Relation between two functions defined by and integral

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, relations, functional-equations

Let us consider the two functions
$$F(x) = \int\limits_x^1 {h(s - x,s)ds - } \int\limits_{1 - x}^1 {h(2 - s - x,s)ds} $$$$G(x) = \int\limits_0^x {h(x - s,s)ds - } \int\limits_0^{1 - x} {h(x + s,s)ds} $$
Where $h$ is some regular function.
Note that $F(0)=-G(0)$, and $F(1)=-G(1)$. But I can not find a general relation between these two functions. I will be grateful to yiur helps.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you share your thoughts, why you think there should be a general relation linking the two functions directly?

Comment: I have some intuition about that by I'm not sure. I've made many of variable substation but I didn't succeed.